# Overriden metadata are still executed in a children custom control class

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I created a DP in a "button" custom control I made:

```
#region IsPressed
public bool IsPressed {
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsPressedProperty); }
    private set { SetValue(IsPressedProperty, value); }
}

private static void IsPressedCallback(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) {
    MyParentClass btn = (MyParentClass) o;
    //change the background when the "button" is pressed, change it back afterward
    if ((bool) args.NewValue) {
        btn._backgroundBrushTemp = btn.Background;
        btn.Background = btn._pressBrush;
    } else {
        btn.Background = btn._backgroundBrushTemp;
    }
}

private readonly static PropertyMetadata IsPressedMetadata = new PropertyMetadata() {
    DefaultValue = false,
    PropertyChangedCallback = IsPressedCallback
};

public static readonly DependencyProperty IsPressedProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("IsPressed", typeof(bool), typeof(MyParentClass), IsPressedMetadata);
#endregion
```

Everything works as intended but users now want a new behavior that would make my custom control way less generic so I created another custom control: MyChildrenClass that inherits MyParentClass.

To implement the new behavior I've to override the IsPressed's callback function so I wrote this in the static ctor of MyChildrenClass:

```
IsPressedProperty.OverrideMetadata(
    typeof(MyChildrenClass),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, IsPressedCallback)
);
```

And wrote the new Callback:

```
private static void IsPressedCallback(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) {
    MyChildrenClass btn = (MyChildrenClass)o;

    //change the background when the "button" is pressed, change it back after 1s
    if ((bool) args.NewValue) {
        btn._backgroundBrushTemp = btn.Background;
        btn.Background = btn._pressBrush;
        if (btn._threadIsPressed == null ||
            !btn._threadIsPressed.IsAlive) {
            btn._threadIsPressed = new Thread(() => {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                btn.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
                    btn.Background = btn._backgroundBrushTemp;
                }));
            });
            btn._threadIsPressed.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem: both callbacks are called even though I've overridden the metadata and the callback function. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You want your derived class to change the behavior of the base. That's really wrong, so whatever problem you're trying to solve, this is not the way to a clean solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do it entirely in XAML:

```
<!--Standard brushes-->
<ImageBrush x:Key="BrushBtnIdle">
    <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
        <BitmapImage>
            <BitmapImage.UriSource>
                <system1:Uri>pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Resources/Images/Btn_Idle.png
                </system1:Uri>
            </BitmapImage.UriSource>
        </BitmapImage>
    </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
</ImageBrush>
<ImageBrush x:Key="BrushBtnPushed">
    <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
        <BitmapImage>
            <BitmapImage.UriSource>
                <system1:Uri>pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Resources/Images/Btn_Pushed.png
                </system1:Uri>
            </BitmapImage.UriSource>
        </BitmapImage>
    </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
</ImageBrush>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyParentClass}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyParentClass}">

                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                        Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}"
                        CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding Border.CornerRadius}" 
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <ContentPresenter  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                       Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                       RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                                       SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                       VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushBtnPushed}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushBtnIdle}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".5"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
<!--Highlighted button-->
<ImageBrush x:Key="BrushBtnHighlight">
    <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
        <BitmapImage>
            <BitmapImage.UriSource>
                <system1:Uri>pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Resources/Images/ActivatedBtn.png
                </system1:Uri>
            </BitmapImage.UriSource>
        </BitmapImage>
    </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
</ImageBrush>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyChildrenClass}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type local:MyParentClass}}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}, Path=IsPressed}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetProperty="Background">
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:01" FillBehavior="Stop">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="{StaticResource BrushBtnHighlight}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Used a StoryBoard in a DataTrigger instead of the Thread.Sleep thing.